# Django: does request.user.id return user's object id (after db query) or only id from cookies?

Tags: django

This question is very interesting to me for performance reasons. If every `request.user.id` sends a query to the database, it's not good, and if it takes the `id` from cookies, it's OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `request.user` is a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object, so it will hit the database. You want to use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/sessions/) middleware, which supports [several backends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SESSION_ENGINE) so, for example, you could use the cache engine and store your sessions in memcache.

If you really want your session data stored as a cookie, the Django development version includes a [cookie-based session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#cookie-session-backend) backend, so you could wait until 1.4 is out or backport it to 1.3 (or use the development version right away).

Comment: request.user is actually a `SimplyLazyObject` object, which only evaluates to a User model when it gets called (and isn't an `AnonymousUser` object)